# Ubuntu 18.04 File or window control Icons not Showing

Tags: 18.04, icons, system

I just upgraded from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS.  Everything seems to be working ok so far, except that the system icons are not showing up.

[image: Screen Shot of Not loading system icons]

The files exist in `/usr/share/icons` and I have all the various theme icons in that folder.  But my installation is not seeing the folder to find the icons.  The Close, minimize, maximize icons don't exist on application windows, and the system icons (power off, Wi-Fi, etc) don't exist either.

I tried creating a symlink to the `usr` folder in my user's home directory to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Install the full Adwaita icon theme by doing this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install adwaita-icon-theme-full
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, it seems the Adwaita icons pack is incomplete and I had to choose another in Gnome Tweaks -> Appearance (I choose Elementary-xfce) :

[image: Gnome tweaks]